# Partial JQuery library, tailored for each project requirement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

The JQuery let's you do all that wonderful stuff, while taking care of browser difference and maintaining a smooth language.

But what if I don't need all of this .. 
Maybe all what I need is just the ajax call (that what most of really want anyway) and I don't want to pay the cost 90+K library just for that feature alone "or with a couple of other features"

Is there a way to "extract" the options you mainly need from JQuery?!
Something similar to what modernizer are doing? See here: http://modernizr.com/download/

Don't get me wrong here, I'm still a "lazy dev" who wouldn't like to reinvent the wheel & care about different browsers compatibility etc. .. so I *still* want to use a library .. but just tailored for my needs.
RobG pointed out the existence of [MyLibrary](http://www.cinsoft.net/mylib.html) which have a builder to deliver what I *"only"* need. Checking it out & it looks very cool. will certainly try it.

Comment: modernizer isn't extracting it's features like you are asking, it is telling you what features the browser supports. If you don't want the weight of jQuery then learn how to use regular javascript...

Comment: jQuery is not modular at all, it's pretty much all or nothing. If you want modular, try [MyLibrary](http://www.cinsoft.net/mylib.html), which has a [builder](http://www.cinsoft.net/mylib-builder.asp) so you can include only the modules you want.

Comment: How about you write your own implementation. If you don't need a library, don't use one.

Comment: What browsers do you need to support?

Comment: Great question; I've often asked myself if this is possible. However bear in mind that a 20K library, self-hosted, might be slower to load than the full version loaded from CDN, which is already in a user's cache much of the time. (See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/17628145/841830 )

Comment: Used zepto https://zeptojs.com/ sometime back, <10K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is can be the answer to the question regarding **how to *extract* jquery needed part(s)**

http://projects.jga.me/jquery-builder/

it divides the library (v1.10.2) to

ajax, css, deprecated($.uaMatch, $.browser, $.sub), dimensions , effects , event-alias , offset & wrap.

But for the *purpose* of the question, *which is not paying that much valuable kilobytes over the precious network*... it turn out that, using this builder, cutting **everything** only reduce the filesize by only 30% ...

so :)  practical solution (till the moment) remains the same 1- not using jquery (use your or another library)  or 2- accept the price of those 90k

Comment: jQuery footprint, once gzipped, is only 30kB, not 90kB, according to their website: https://jquery.com/. And it's supposed to be cached, so it will only be loaded once.

Answer (score 1):

You can get an unminified copy of the jQuery source and remove the methods you don't need. Just be careful with removing methods that AJAX might have dependencies on.

Comment: That seem a very good option especially when considering that tool @BrettWeber just mentioned [jQuerySourceViewer](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/)

Answer (score 1):

For those developers who aren't "lazy dev"s, getting examples of what you are trying to do from the source of any open source libraries and forming your own modules is a great way to go.

There are resources out there to get you to just snippets you need such as [Micro.js](http://microjs.com/#) and [james padolsey's jquery source viewer](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/).

Once you have build a nice set of modules and established what dependencies you have internally, you can create min files specific to a page or portion of a project and cutting out all of the extra weight you don't need

Comment: well , I'm not "lazy dev" when it comes to creating my library, :D Thank you for the links and hints ... checking 'em out !